# Found money on the running road ...Is it Haram to use it?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

When I was on my way to play football game towards ground in the evening  ..I  found some amount of money on the running road that touches our ground . I don't know who is the owner of that amount so is it Haram to utilize it in our basic need ...if yes then where I can dispose off this money..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you finds an item on the road, pathway or a public gathering, it is haraam for you to pick it up and keep it for himself.
If you finds something and does not pick it up, there will be no sin for you.However, if you finds it at a place where there is the fear that if you do not pick it up, someone else will pick it up and will not return it to it’s owner, then it becomes wajib on you to pick it up and return it to it’s owner.
If a you finds a lost item and picks it up, it becomes your responsibility to search for it’s owner and to return it to him.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that money can be given out to sadaka if you couldn't find the owner .

Comment: Yup you are right @SongBird